# Automatically install services from folder when starting

Tags: service, arangodb

I'm currently running `arangodb` using docker and I want to be able to start with a clean slate just by restarting my containers.

I have mounted volumes in docker where I want the code of my services to be mounted.

How can I automatically have `arangodb` install those services? I want to be able to edit the code in the volume to be able to develop my services without having to upload them again. Also it is important that I can run VCS directly in the mounted volume from my client machine.

Answer (score 0):

The ArangoDB container has script hooks that can be used in derived containers by placing files in specific directories:

```
FROM arangodb/testdrivearangodocker
MAINTAINER Frank Celler <info@arangodb.com>

COPY test.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY test.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY dumps /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dumps

COPY verify.js /
```

As [we demonstrate in this testcontainer](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker/tree/official/test-user-scripts).

- the dumps directory will be restored using arangorestore
- .js files will be executed using arangosh
- .sh files will be executed

This [script mechanism is implemented in this part of the docker entrypoint script](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker/blob/official/docker-entrypoint34.sh#L109).

With ArangoDB 3.3 you can use the old foxx-manager to install services, ArangoDB 3.4 on [you may use foxx-cli](https://github.com/arangodb/foxx-cli) for that purpose.